# Is there any way to get Robux other than Making Games or Microtransactions or Paying?

Tags: roblox

The only way to make a good Roblox game is to have good coding skills, I'm not a good coder. The only other options I'm left with to make Roblox are microtransactions or paying some cash. I don't want to waste money and I don't have a friend who willing to share their Robux.

There are many avatar clothing on Roblox that are not free.

Is there any other way to get Robux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using Bing search engine daily and Microsoft Rewards. You will need many points, so use Bing search only if you can, and do the challenges daily (most involve only clicking and closing the tab that opens). When you can afford the Microsoft Store gift cards with your points, get it. Then download Roblox "app" from Microsoft Store, and go to buy Robux within the app. There it will go through the Microsoft Store and you can use your credit from Microsoft Rewards Microsoft Store gift cards.

You can also get Robux gift card codes directly from Microsoft Rewards (at least in Canada)

Answer (score 9):

**No, this is impossible through the game.** According to [Roblox](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313200-Ways-to-Get-Robux),

> There is no such thing as a Robux Generator. If a person, website, or
> game tries to tell you there is one, this is a scam and should be
> reported via our Report Abuse system.

These fake games attempt to steal your password, so avoid them and remember that you can only get Robux by purchasing them.

But, **you have the slight possibility to receive gift cards by official giveaways** or other such methods, such as Bing rewards.

Comment: Your answer provides ways to report scams, which is good but Corsaka's answer provides a way to get free Robux (via gift card giveaway).

Comment: No Microsoft Rward

Comment: @RayWu Ok, I added that into my answer. If you have a suggestion, please consider editing. It helps speed things up.

Comment: @OKprogrammer but this is not official giveaway? It's guaranteed if you have the points, I used Bing for a year and got Premium

Comment: @RayWu Ok, it has been added.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. The only possible method of getting Robux for free legally is by winning a gift card giveaway.

Any external method that promises free robux for nothing in return will NEVER work.

Comment: This is not true. Nucriosoft Rewards can give it to you

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to get free Robux, although both are tedious and probably not worth it:

- **Microsoft Rewards**:
  One of the rewards of the Microsoft Rewards are the Robux Gift Cards, as you can see here > https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/rewards/robux-edge-offer.
- **Robux Social Contests**:
  Perhaps the best social network for this is Twitter, search for "Robux Gift Card" and locate reliable accounts that give away robux among their followers, such as https://twitter.com/kolbysnister

But you will not be able to get free Robux:

- **Within any roblox game or Roblox platform**:
  What you can find are many free items. Or items that you can buy with the exclusive coins of each game
- **On any page that says you can earn Robux**:
  They are all scams that will make you waste your time or directly pages with malware